# fundamental neighborhood of $i\infty$

Tags: modular-forms

My problem is to understand why the set $\lbrace z\in \mathbb{H} :Im(z)>c\rbrace$ $\cup \lbrace i\infty \rbrace$ is a fundamental neighborhood for $i\infty$  , where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane . Is it because  a point in this set is greater  than any natural number c ?

Comment: There's no such thing as $i\infty$ in standard usage in complex analysis - you need to give us your _definition_ of "fundamental neighborhood of $i\infty$". (Of course there _is_ a standard notion of $\infty$ in complex -- that set is _not_ a neighborhood of $\infty$.)

Comment: The edit doesn't change anything. We still don't know the definition of "fundamental neighborhood of $i\infty$ (and, relvant or not, $\{\Im z>c\}\cup\{\infty\}$ is still not a neighborhood of $\infty$.)

Comment: In the literature is is written that $\lbrace z\in F :im(z)>c \rbrace$ $\cup$ $\lbrace i \infty \rbrace$ where F is the  standard fundamental domain , is a fundamental  neighborhood of $i \infty$

Comment: If you say so. You still haven't given us that definition.